# How to display page loading time in drupal 7 for each page

Tags: theming

I want to display page loading time in every page in the footer. I can do this through some custom php script but want to know that is there any drupal way to achieve this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a custom one line php script to display the page loading time in every page.

```
<?php 
 printf('<div>Page loaded in %.3f seconds.</div>',  (microtime(TRUE) - $_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT'])); 

?>
```

put this at last line in *html.tpl.php*

Answer (score 1):

The [Devel](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel) module will show queries and their execution time in the footer which will get you an idea of how long the page is loading.

Comment: Well! For acheiving better page loading optimization the all heavy modules (specially devel module) is always remain disabled in production enviroment

Comment: @MdEqbalAhmad Yep - for _exactly_ the same reason you wouldn't put your load times at the bottom of the page on a production site - you'd use proper analytics software (think New Relic). You're either developing or you're not!

Answer (score 0):

In addition to [Devel](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel), the core statistics module has a report on pages taking the most time.

However, from your response to @ScottJoudry, I gather that you're *not* looking for a diagnostic tool, but something lightweight that just displays this data to entertain you and the site's users.

In that case, you need to roll your own PHP script.